# Node Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module even though I'm not

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, pm2

I am using Pm2 and this is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

The issue is, the `package.json` is already set to `"type": "module"`.

Also, everything used to work fine until I restart the server.

Here is the actual `.js` file:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const querystring = require('querystring');
    
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 8080;
    
import captureWebsite from 'capture-website';


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World!\n');
    
    ....
});
```

Comment: @fast-reflexes Can you give a code example? Not too familiar with Node.

Comment: @fast-reflexes Hmm, it says those are fine as they are though. The error is only with `import captureWebsite from 'capture-website';`

Comment: @fast-reflexes That's fine and all, but the error is `import captureWebsite from 'capture-website';`. That line is what is causing the error. Can we just focus on that please

Comment: Node is just javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `require` calls are not throwing an error, the "actual `.js` file" creating the http server in the post is being treated as CommonJS. But CommonJS code can't use `import` statements and needs to use *import expressions* instead (see [node](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs)  and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) docs).

If you use dynamic imports ( which are asynchronous) you would also need to use the imported module after an `await` statement (inside an `async` function), or in a success handler provided in a `then` method:

```
// ....

import('capture_website')
.then( capture_website => {
      // code requiring existence of `capture_website`
 })
.catch( err=> console.error("Import of capture_website failed", err));
```

However you can import CommonJS modules using an import statement in ES6 files ([Node doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs)).

Hence a better solution may be to rename the main `js` file posted to give it a `.mjs` extension, and replace all the require statements in the file with `import` statements:

```
import http from 'http';
import url from 'url';
import querystring from 'querystring';
```

This gets rid of the `Cannot use import statement outside a module` syntax error. Imported modules that are CommonJS should still be able to require modules using the `require` function.